# how to get table wise number of deadlocks in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, deadlock

I am experiencing deadlocks in Sql Server 2014.

I am aware that we can get total number of deadlocks using performance counters in Sql Server Ref: **Number of Deadlocks/sec** from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance-monitor/sql-server-locks-object

I would like to know if there is a way to get deadlock count per table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is pretty easy to do using the `xml_deadlock_report` in the `system_health` Extended Event session.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..[#DeadlockData]') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #DeadlockData;

WITH xml
AS ( SELECT CAST(event_data AS XML) AS XMLDATA
     FROM   sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file('system_health*.xel', NULL, NULL, NULL) )
SELECT xml.XMLDATA
INTO   #DeadlockData
FROM   xml
WHERE  xml.XMLDATA.value('(/event/@name)[1]', 'varchar(255)') = 'xml_deadlock_report';


WITH death_indeed
AS ( SELECT ca.x.value('@objectname', 'VARCHAR(256)') AS object_name
     FROM   #DeadlockData AS dd
     CROSS APPLY dd.XMLDATA.nodes('//resource-list/*') AS ca(x) )
SELECT   death_indeed.object_name, COUNT_BIG(*) AS deaths
FROM     death_indeed
GROUP BY death_indeed.object_name
```

After creating some different deadlocks, I get this back:

```
object_name                deaths
StackOverflow.dbo.Users    9
StackOverflow.dbo.Posts    9
```